# Подключить cs файл из другой папки

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Никак не получается подключить cs файл.

Файл "MyClasses.cs" лежит "c:\Prg\src\MyClass.cs". Проект в "c:\Prg\src\Parser".

```
namespace MyClasses
{
...
```

Файл добавил в обозревателе решений "добавить существующий элемент".

```
using MyClasses;
```

Файл отображается в обозревателе решений в папочке "Solution Items".
Получаю ошибку "Не удалось найти....".

Comment: Переместите файл в проект Parser

Comment: Это понятно... Мне как раз нужно вне проекта файл держать. Несколько проектов с одним набором классов раюотают. Чтобы файл актуален был.

Comment: Для этого создают другой проект по типу библиотека компонентов,классов,утилит и добавляют его

Comment: угу, где старый добрый include ...